# Django, running 'test' returns the path to my command files

Tags: django, testing

I enter: ./manage.py test

I get back: /full/path/to/project/app/commands/

as a string.

This makes no sense. It's been a week since I ran tests, but it worked fine then. So, I've done something to mung it up, but I don't know where to start.

Comment: There is a  test.py in commands. Renaming that fixes the problem.  You should add an answer 'take the test.py out of the commands folder' so I can upvote/star it.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have the `test.py` inside the `commands` package under any of your project apps. If it exists, it is *shadowing the built-in `test` command*. Remove it.

Additionally, if you would run `python manage.py` it would output the list of all available commands grouped by apps they are introduced in. This could have helped to debug the problem by checking where is the `test` command coming from:

```
$ python manage.py
...
[auth]
    changepassword
    createsuperuser

[django]
    check
    cleanup
    compilemessages
...
[django_nose]
    test
...
[staticfiles]
    collectstatic
    findstatic
    runserver
```

As you can see, in this example `test` is coming from the `django_nose` app - since I'm using `nose` as a test runner.